# Probability of a car accident

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

Recently I was visited by a car insurance policy expert to renew a contract and I was told that I had a (fatal/non-fatal) car accident risk of %35 so my policy would differ. He also provided me with separate fatal and non-fatal accident probabilities.

Since then, I have been trying to come to a conclusion as to how this percentage is formulated. I have had 2 minor accidents (bumper kiss as they call it here) last year which were not even reported and I drive a common mid level car. Even if all accident data is brought to consideration 35% sounds too high.

How could this "probability" be calculated?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you know that $78.89$% of statistics is made up on the spot.

Comment: I believe everything I see on the internet

Comment: This question has nothing to do with math. You should ask it on some insurance related site.

Comment: @Graffitics I don't agree. This is all about probabilities and [actuarial science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_science), which heavily uses maths. There is even a tag for this! While there is probably not enough knowledge to explain in full this particular value with maths, it seems possible to at least explain a bit how such things are actually computed.

Comment: Former actuarial analyst here. This information is likely very confidential, and is likely dependent on the data the insurance company has gathered. Insurance companies are particularly uptight about maintaining confidentiality of their rates, so you're likely not going to find an answer.

Comment: @Clarinetist I don't need aything exact actually. I'm only curious about the general logic in these calculations. I (we?) would be grateful if you could share any part of your knowledge that would not create trouble for you.

Comment: @mechanicum If you would like an introduction to the general concept, I recommend *Models for Quantifying Risk* by Camilli et al. (6th ed), or *Actuarial Mathematics for Life Contingent Risks* by Dickson et al. (2nd ed.). These mainly focus on life insurance modeling. I don't know much about the property-casualty side (which car insurance would be under); for that, you might want to go to the Actuarial Outpost and create an account.